# What are some different predators I can add for my world building?

Tags: monsters, animals, world-building

I'm currently building a fantasy world to use in a future campaign, and I need some ideas and descriptions of different apex predators, both rare and common, to add to my world.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange, could you edit your question to add additional information about your campaign - like which game it is and what you currently have in the setting? At present its a bit of a vague question and may be closed

Comment: This question would be a better fit for [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Kryomaani it would be closed as off-topic there.

Comment: @VLAZ [Wordlbuilding SE help](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) explicitly states "flora and fauna" are **on-topic**. With this little information and no prior research it would likely be closed as *too broad*, but this is absolutely *not* "off-topic" for Worldbuilding.

Comment: @Kryomaani *this* question that we see right now would be closed. A different question might not be. But that's not what you suggested. When directing people to different sites *and* they've already asked a close-worthy question, it's a disservice to both the site and the user to simply try and "shoo" them away elsewhere without making sure to mention they have to ask an on-topic question. WB in particular is plagued by a lot of users being directed to it with no proper guidance, so an already unclear question often gets closed on one stack, copied to WB, then closed there, too.